# Not Able to Push Arrays into Array (Making Array of Arrays)

Tags: javascript

can you please take a look at this snippet and let me know why I am not able to create an array of array at this example?

```js
var data1 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];
var data2 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];
var data3 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];
var data4 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];

var all = [];
all[0].push(data1);
all[1].push(data2);
all[2].push(data3);
all[3].push(data4);

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(all);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For future reference, try to look at the cause of these types of behavior earlier. If you had done `console.log(all[0])` it would have been pretty evident what was going on.

Comment: For future reference (2), read the error console. (It would have thrown a JavaScript error on `all[0].push` - if nothing else this sort of 'failing' message should be reported in diagnostics/questions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be doing `all.push(dataX)` since `all[X]` is `undefined`.

```
var data1 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];
var data2 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];
var data3 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];
var data4 = [5555,22,102858,12,.554,88888,99999999,12,1.5];

var all = [];
all.push(data1);
all.push(data2);
all.push(data3);
all.push(data4);

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(all);
console.log(myJsonString);
```

Explanation:

In the code you wrote, `all` is an empty `Array`.

`all[X]` (e.g. `all[0]`) refers to the first element of the array, which doesn't exist (since array is empty).  JavaScript interprets this as `undefined`. (There is no array out of bounds exception)

`undefined` has no method `.push(...)` which is why your code is failing.

What you want is to call `all.push(...)` where you're calling `.push(...)` on the `all` `Array`.

Comment: Thanks arc but kinda confusing! why isn't the all acting like all other arrays?!

Comment: If you want to access the array by index, you can write `all[0] = data1;`. Generally, it's considered cleaner to use other language features so you don't have to rely on perfect hand-counting of indices.

Answer (score 2):

```
all[0].push(data1);
```

`all[0]` retrieves the first element of `all`. Since you just made the array and it's empty, this is `undefined`. (In other languages, it would be an array index access violation). You're then trying to push onto that first element; if it were an array itself, this would give you `[[[5555,22,...` which is one more array container than you want.

Easiest solution is to construct the array via a literal.

```
var all = [data1, data2, data3, data4];
// no "push()" necessary here.
```